# Facebook SDK ads not working without AdSettings.addTestDevice

Tags: android, ads, facebook-sdk-4.x

Here is my code where I load ads:

```
        adView = new AdView(this,getResources().getString(R.string.facebook_ad_id) , AdSize.BANNER_320_50);
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.adView);
    layout.addView(adView);
    //AdSettings.addTestDevice("d0750cd2c16e48849a32688beeaa1890");
    adView.loadAd();
```

This code won't work unless I uncomment the AdSettings.addTestDevice(), and this is the problem. I want see if it works for release.

Here's the logcat when I try to load ad:

```
    05-25 15:34:09.253 13334-13572/h2d.drawteam.howtodraw D/IMGSRV: gralloc_register_buffer:1390: hnd=0x55725c6890 ID=280842 fd=88 ref=1
05-25 15:34:09.253 13334-13572/h2d.drawteam.howtodraw D/GraphicBuffer: register, handle(0x55725c6890) (w:1080 h:1920 s:1088 f:0x1 u:0x000b00)
05-25 15:34:09.310 13334-13334/h2d.drawteam.howtodraw V/SettingsInterface:  from settings cache , name = sound_effects_enabled , value = 1
05-25 15:34:09.328 13334-22002/h2d.drawteam.howtodraw E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.AttributionIdProvider
05-25 15:34:09.332 13334-13334/h2d.drawteam.howtodraw D/ColorDrawable: Color = -1118482, canvas = android.view.GLES20RecordingCanvas@6b66443, mTintMode = SRC_IN, mTint = null, ColorDrawable = android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable@1f5f1cdd
05-25 15:34:09.393 13334-22004/h2d.drawteam.howtodraw I/System.out: [CDS]rx timeout:1
05-25 15:34:09.394 13334-22004/h2d.drawteam.howtodraw I/System.out: [CDS]rx timeout:1
05-25 15:34:09.394 13334-22004/h2d.drawteam.howtodraw D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x557258cde0 sslRead buf=0x55727744e0 len=2048,timeo=10
05-25 15:34:09.396 13334-22004/h2d.drawteam.howtodraw D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x557258cde0 info_callback where=0x4004 ret=256
05-25 15:34:09.396 13334-22004/h2d.drawteam.howtodraw D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x557258cde0 SSL3 alert read:W:CN warning close notify
05-25 15:34:09.396 13334-22004/h2d.drawteam.howtodraw D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x557258cde0 info_callback ignored
05-25 15:34:09.396 13334-22004/h2d.drawteam.howtodraw I/System.out: [CDS]rx timeout:8000
05-25 15:34:09.396 13334-22004/h2d.drawteam.howtodraw I/System.out: [CDS]rx timeout:8000
05-25 15:34:09.396 13334-22004/h2d.drawteam.howtodraw I/System.out: Close in OkHttp:0
05-25 15:34:09.396 13334-22004/h2d.drawteam.howtodraw D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x557258cde0 NativeCrypto_SSL_interrupt
05-25 15:34:09.396 13334-22004/h2d.drawteam.howtodraw D/NativeCrypto:  sslNotify, appData=0x5572417de0 ret=1
05-25 15:34:09.396 13334-22004/h2d.drawteam.howtodraw D/NativeCrypto:  sslNotify, appData=0x5572417de0 ret=1
05-25 15:34:09.396 13334-22004/h2d.drawteam.howtodraw D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x557258cde0 info_callback where=0x4008 ret=256
05-25 15:34:09.396 13334-22004/h2d.drawteam.howtodraw D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x557258cde0 SSL3 alert write:W:CN warning close notify
05-25 15:34:09.396 13334-22004/h2d.drawteam.howtodraw D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x557258cde0 info_callback ignored
05-25 15:34:09.397 13334-22004/h2d.drawteam.howtodraw I/System.out: [CDS]close[49487]
05-25 15:34:09.397 13334-22004/h2d.drawteam.howtodraw D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: hostname=graph.facebook.com; servname=(null); cache_mode=(null), netid=0; mark=0
05-25 15:34:09.397 13334-22004/h2d.drawteam.howtodraw D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: ai_addrlen=0; ai_canonname=(null); ai_flags=4; ai_family=0
05-25 15:34:09.397 13334-22004/h2d.drawteam.howtodraw D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: hostname=graph.facebook.com; servname=(null); cache_mode=(null), netid=0; mark=0
05-25 15:34:09.397 13334-22004/h2d.drawteam.howtodraw D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: ai_addrlen=0; ai_canonname=(null); ai_flags=1024; ai_family=0
05-25 15:34:09.415 13334-22004/h2d.drawteam.howtodraw D/libc-netbsd: getaddrinfo: graph.facebook.com get result from proxy >>
05-25 15:34:09.415 13334-22004/h2d.drawteam.howtodraw I/System.out: propertyValue:true
05-25 15:34:09.420 13334-22004/h2d.drawteam.howtodraw I/System.out: [CDS]rx timeout:8000
05-25 15:34:09.421 13334-22004/h2d.drawteam.howtodraw I/System.out: [socket][3] connection graph.facebook.com/31.13.92.10:443;LocalPort=36844(0)
05-25 15:34:09.421 13334-22004/h2d.drawteam.howtodraw I/System.out: [CDS]connect[graph.facebook.com/31.13.92.10:443] tm:90
05-25 15:34:09.422 13334-22004/h2d.drawteam.howtodraw D/Posix: [Posix_connect Debug]Process h2d.drawteam.howtodraw :443 
05-25 15:34:09.455 13334-22004/h2d.drawteam.howtodraw I/System.out: [socket][/192.168.1.107:36844] connected
05-25 15:34:09.460 13334-22004/h2d.drawteam.howtodraw D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x5572747e30 NativeCrypto_SSL_do_handshake fd=0x7f7c141f94 shc=0x7f7c141f98 timeout_millis=8000 client_mode=1 npn=0x0
05-25 15:34:09.460 13334-22004/h2d.drawteam.howtodraw D/NativeCrypto: doing handshake ++
05-25 15:34:09.460 13334-22004/h2d.drawteam.howtodraw D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x5572747e30 info_callback where=0x10 ret=1
05-25 15:34:09.460 13334-22004/h2d.drawteam.howtodraw D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x5572747e30 handshake start in UNKWN  before/connect initialization
05-25 15:34:09.460 13334-22004/h2d.drawteam.howtodraw D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x5572747e30 info_callback calling handshakeCompleted
05-25 15:34:09.460 13334-22004/h2d.drawteam.howtodraw D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x5572747e30 info_callback completed
05-25 15:34:09.460 13334-22004/h2d.drawteam.howtodraw D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x5572747e30 info_callback where=0x1001 ret=1
05-25 15:34:09.460 13334-22004/h2d.drawteam.howtodraw D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x5572747e30 SSL_connect:UNKWN  before/connect initialization
05-25 15:34:09.460 13334-22004/h2d.drawteam.howtodraw D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x5572747e30 info_callback ignored
05-25 15:34:09.460 13334-22004/h2d.drawteam.howtodraw D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x5572747e30 info_callback where=0x1001 ret=1
05-25 15:34:09.460 13334-22004/h2d.drawteam.howtodraw D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x5572747e30 SSL_connect:3WCH_A SSLv3 write client hello A
05-25 15:34:09.460 13334-22004/h2d.drawteam.howtodraw D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x5572747e30 info_callback ignored
05-25 15:34:09.460 13334-22004/h2d.drawteam.howtodraw D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x5572747e30 info_callback where=0x1002 ret=-1
05-25 15:34:09.460 13334-22004/h2d.drawteam.howtodraw D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x5572747e30 SSL_connect:error exit in 3RSH_A SSLv3 read server hello A
05-25 15:34:09.460 13334-22004/h2d.drawteam.howtodraw D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x5572747e30 info_callback ignored
05-25 15:34:09.460 13334-22004/h2d.drawteam.howtodraw D/NativeCrypto: doing handshake -- ret=-1
05-25 15:34:09.460 13334-22004/h2d.drawteam.howtodraw D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x5572747e30 NativeCrypto_SSL_do_handshake ret=-1 errno=11 sslError=2 timeout_millis=8000
05-25 15:34:09.494 13334-22004/h2d.drawteam.howtodraw D/NativeCrypto: doing handshake ++
05-25 15:34:09.494 13334-22004/h2d.drawteam.howtodraw D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x5572747e30 info_callback where=0x1001 ret=1
05-25 15:34:09.494 13334-22004/h2d.drawteam.howtodraw D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x5572747e30 SSL_connect:3RSH_A SSLv3 read server hello A
05-25 15:34:09.494 13334-22004/h2d.drawteam.howtodraw D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x5572747e30 info_callback ignored
05-25 15:34:09.494 13334-22004/h2d.drawteam.howtodraw D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x5572747e30 info_callback where=0x1001 ret=1
05-25 15:34:09.494 13334-22004/h2d.drawteam.howtodraw D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x5572747e30 SSL_connect:3RFINA SSLv3 read finished A
05-25 15:34:09.494 13334-22004/h2d.drawteam.howtodraw D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x5572747e30 info_callback ignored
05-25 15:34:09.494 13334-22004/h2d.drawteam.howtodraw D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x5572747e30 info_callback where=0x1001 ret=1
05-25 15:34:09.494 13334-22004/h2d.drawteam.howtodraw D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x5572747e30 SSL_connect:3WCCSA SSLv3 write change cipher spec A
05-25 15:34:09.494 13334-22004/h2d.drawteam.howtodraw D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x5572747e30 info_callback ignored
05-25 15:34:09.494 13334-22004/h2d.drawteam.howtodraw D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x5572747e30 info_callback where=0x1001 ret=1
05-25 15:34:09.494 13334-22004/h2d.drawteam.howtodraw D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x5572747e30 SSL_connect:3WFINA SSLv3 write finished A
05-25 15:34:09.494 13334-22004/h2d.drawteam.howtodraw D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x5572747e30 info_callback ignored
05-25 15:34:09.494 13334-22004/h2d.drawteam.howtodraw D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x5572747e30 info_callback where=0x1001 ret=1
05-25 15:34:09.494 13334-22004/h2d.drawteam.howtodraw D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x5572747e30 SSL_connect:3FLUSH SSLv3 flush data
05-25 15:34:09.494 13334-22004/h2d.drawteam.howtodraw D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x5572747e30 info_callback ignored
05-25 15:34:09.494 13334-22004/h2d.drawteam.howtodraw D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x5572747e30 info_callback where=0x20 ret=1
05-25 15:34:09.494 13334-22004/h2d.drawteam.howtodraw D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x5572747e30 handshake done in SSLOK  SSL negotiation finished successfully
05-25 15:34:09.494 13334-22004/h2d.drawteam.howtodraw D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x5572747e30 info_callback calling handshakeCompleted
05-25 15:34:09.494 13334-22004/h2d.drawteam.howtodraw D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x5572747e30 info_callback completed
05-25 15:34:09.494 13334-22004/h2d.drawteam.howtodraw D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x5572747e30 info_callback where=0x1002 ret=1
05-25 15:34:09.494 13334-22004/h2d.drawteam.howtodraw D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x5572747e30 SSL_connect:ok exit in SSLOK  SSL negotiation finished successfully
05-25 15:34:09.494 13334-22004/h2d.drawteam.howtodraw D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x5572747e30 info_callback ignored
05-25 15:34:09.494 13334-22004/h2d.drawteam.howtodraw D/NativeCrypto: doing handshake -- ret=1
05-25 15:34:09.494 13334-22004/h2d.drawteam.howtodraw I/System.out: gba_cipher_suite:TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
05-25 15:34:09.495 13334-22004/h2d.drawteam.howtodraw I/System.out: [OkHttp] sendRequest>>
05-25 15:34:09.495 13334-22004/h2d.drawteam.howtodraw I/System.out: [OkHttp] sendRequest<<
05-25 15:34:09.495 13334-22004/h2d.drawteam.howtodraw D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x5572747e30 sslWrite buf=0x55727744e0 len=1079 write_timeout_millis=0
05-25 15:34:09.495 13334-22004/h2d.drawteam.howtodraw D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x5572747e30 sslRead buf=0x55727744e0 len=2048,timeo=8000
```

I suspect that `E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.AttributionIdProvider` error should tell me something, but as far as I googled it has something to do with permissions or wrong ID's, but all of them are correctly setup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out that Facebook does not give ads until the application is approved by the administrators in the Facebook developer console.